# Data no inserted to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner and trying to follow some tutorial videos for my school project. I am stuck when the data not inserted into the database. I double-check the code to tutorial and nothing wrong. There's no error message or notification too. I really appreciate your help.

action.php

```
 <!--action.php-->
    <?php
        require 'config.php';

        if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
            $pid    = $_POST['pid'];
            $pname  = $_POST['pname'];      
            $pprice = $_POST['pprice'];
            $pimage = $_POST['pimage'];
            $pcode  = $_POST['pcode'];
            $pqty   = 1;

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_code FROM cart WHERE product_code=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$pcode);
            $stmt->execute();
            $res = $stmt->get_result();
            $r = $res->fetch_assoc();
            $code = $r['product_code'];

            if(!$code){
                $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (product_name,product_price,product_image,qty,total_price,produk_code) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $query->bind_param("sssiss",$pname,$pprice,$pimage,$pqty,$pprice,$pcode);
                $query->execute();

                echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong>Item added to cart!</strong> 
                      </div>';      
            }
            else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                          <strong>Item already added to your cart!</strong> 
                      </div>';
            } 
        }
    ?>
```

index.php

```
<!--index.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map Store</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fc847822ba.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Map Store</a>

      <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- Navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Category</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="cart.php">Checkout</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="cart.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-white"> <span id="cart-item" class="badge badge-danger">0</span> </i></a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div id="message">

            </div>
            <?php
                include 'config.php';
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <div class="card p-2 border-secondary mb-2">
                        <img src="<?= $row['product_image'] ?>" class="card-img-top" height="250">
                        <div class="card-body p-1">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center text-info"><?= $row['product_name']?></h4>
                            <h5 class="card-text text-center text-danger"><?= number_format($row
                                ['product_price'],2) ?>/-</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer p-1">
                            <form action="#" class="form-submit"> 
                                <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?= $row['id']?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?= $row['product_name']?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="<?= $row['product_price']?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pimage" value="<?= $row['product_image']?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pcode" value="<?= $row['product_code']?>">
                                <button class="btn btn-info btn-block addItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus "></i>Add to cart</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".addItemBtn").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form   = $(this).closest(".form-submit");
                var pid     = $form.find(".pid").val();
                var pname   = $form.find(".pname").val();
                var pprice  = $form.find(".pprice").val();
                var pimage  = $form.find(".pimage").val();
                var pcode   = $form.find(".pcode").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'action.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {pid:pid,pname:pname,pprice:pprice,pimage:pimage,pcode:pcode},
                    success:function(response){
                        $("message").html(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

config.php

```
<!--config.php-->
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","checkout_system");
        if($conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection Failed!".$conn->connect_error);
        }
?>
```

sorry i am new  here and this my first post

Comment: you have `produk_code` in `INSERT INTO cart (product_name,product_price,product_image,qty,total_price,produk_code)` is that a typo?

Comment: There is no error message because you didn't check for mysql error, follow the answer from this thread to enable your mysql report in PHP and see what is the problem.

Comment: produk  ?  Really?

Comment: thank you, sir, for your answer and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML elements in your form must have a `name` attribute to be available in `$_POST`, you set only a `class` :

```
<input type="hidden" name="pid" class="pid" value="<?= $row['id']?>">
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer